# How can I loop through a list of commands (list.txt) in a bash script?

Tags: bash, wget

I have a list of 1000 commands in a txt file and I want to execute them one by one in cmd. So I wrote this loop for them:

```
for command in list.txt;
do
  $command
done
```

or

```
while read command
do
  $command
done < list.txt
```

None works though! Should I indicate the separator by `IFS` ? the commands are wget commands like:

```
wget -w 3 --random-wait url -o filename
```

and they are each on a separate line in list.txt. and last but no least, is there any way to make a delay between each command? When I copy paste all of the commands at once it ignores the delay that I indicated in my wget command and it wouldn't treat the server nicely!!

Comment: you mean 'eval $command' ? I already tried and it doesn't work!

Comment: Care to explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? Does your computer crash? Is the power on?

Comment: CMD window opens up and closes without doing anything. the only way that it works is when I copy paste all of the commands at once in cmd which is too fast and doesn't make any delay which could be not well for the server!

Comment: Also I made a batch file out of that command list and it doesn't work!

Comment: If each line in `list.txt` is actually a valid command, you can simply use `source list.txt`.

Comment: Sounds like it's a DOS-formatted text file. You'll need to trim the trailing newlines before you can either `eval` *or* execute its contents.

Comment: BTW, `eval "$command"`, not `eval $command`. Quote expansions even when it's not mandatory, and you won't get yourself in trouble when it is. But to deal with your DOS-newline problem, you want `eval "${command%$'\r'}"`.

Comment: ...but, waitaminute, "CMD window opens up and closes"? Running `eval` in bash shouldn't open a new window at all. Are you sure your interpreter really is bash?

Comment: `for command in list.txt` is wrong, btw. See BashFAQ #1 for notes on how to correctly read a file line-by-line -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: By the way -- if you want to know what's going wrong, `set -x` is your friend (at the top of the script), or `bash -x yourscript` (to run it).

Comment: Thanks! now it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea, but if you must:

```
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
  line=${line%$'\r'} # trim DOS newlines
  printf 'Evaluating following line: %s\n' "$line" >&2
  eval "$line"
  sleep 1
done 3<list.txt
```

Notable items:

- Using a `while read` loop avoids numerous caveats involved in reading files otherwise. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). [Also, `for line in foo.txt` only iterates once, with `foo.txt` -- the filename itself -- as the value of `$line`, so that's *never* correct].

  - Using the `-r` argument to `read` causes backslash literals to be honored.
  - Clearing the `IFS` variable prevents leading and trailing whitespace from being stripped.
  - Using file descriptor 3 for file content prevents any commands run from the file from consuming stdin, and thus preventing the rest of the file from being run.
- DOS text files use CRLF newlines, whereas UNIX text files use CRs. only. `$'\r'` is the bash representation of a LF character; `${foo%$'\r'}` is a parameter expansions which strips any trailing LF from variable `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a file `list.txt` of bash commands:

```
echo 'Command #1'
ls -1
echo 'Command #2'
sar 1 2
echo 'Command #3'
hostname
```

Just execute all the commands in the file by running:

```
bash list.txt
```

Example output would be:

```
Command #1
list.txt
Command #2
Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 (my.server.org)        06/02/2016      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

08:56:48 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
08:56:49 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.99      0.00      0.00     99.01
08:56:50 AM     all     16.00      0.00     14.00      1.00      0.00     69.00
Average:        all      7.96      0.00      7.46      0.50      0.00     84.08
Command #3
my.server.org
```

With regard to your request for delays, try increasing the wait time (`wget -w 10`) or adding a `sleep 10` to your `list.txt` file after each command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really even need a script for that.

```
$ cat list.txt | xargs $command
```

If your command can only handle one argument at a time.

```
$ cat list.txt | xargs -n 1 $command
```

Comment: The `command` itself is coming from the list, not just the arguments for it.

Comment: Isn't that just a bash script itself? So bash list.txt?

Comment: Except that the OP wants a delay between execution of each command in the list, yes.